# Is there anything wrong with re-asking and re-answering questions from Google+?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've never participated in a private Stack Exchange beta, and I'm wondering if it's good form to seed the site with earlier questions. Some could overlap with the documentation, like "How can I work with multiple local domains without buying licenses for each?".

I'm thinking questions with specific answers (not "Who likes Craft?!"), just ones that I'd be repeatedly asking as my previous self and answering from the present day.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a blog post I often quote when the issue of "seeding" a new site comes up:

[**Your New Site: Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)

Every community is different and every launch is different. I really don't suspect there will be a problem with asking some of your favorite questions here, but be aware that it *can* be overdone. A site can start to look somewhat forced and uninteresting if folks are just reiterating documentation or just spitting out questions ***because*** they've already been answered elsewhere.

I suspect many of these questions will be asked again organically if you let them come in their own good time, but asking questions you recall from having interesting problems in the past can be a great source of interesting content for a site. Have a look a the blog post I linked above to at least be aware of issues. And then just relax, let the whole thing come together organically, and enjoy your new site!

Comment: Thanks Robert. I just finished reading that post, so your answer is helpful reinforcement. I think it's safe to say I should chill out and only ask some really good ones. I don't want to establish myself as the Gollum of the exchange, talking to myself all over the place and looking like a jerk.